# Installing specific apt version with ansible

Tags: ansible

I used an ansible playbook to install git:

```yaml
---
- hosts: "www"
  tasks:
  - name: Update apt repo
    apt: update_cache=yes
  - name: Install dependencies
    apt: name={{item}} state=installed
    with_items:
      - git
```

I checked the installed versions:

```sh
$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
```

But adding these to the ansible playbook: `apt: name=git=1.9.1 state=installed`

and rerunning results in the following error:

> fatal: [46.101.94.110]: FAILED! => {"cache_update_time": 0,
> "cache_updated": false, "changed": false, "failed": true, "msg":
> "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o
> "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold"     install 'git=1.9.1'' failed:
> E: Version '1.9.1' for 'git' was not found\n", "stderr": "E: Version
> '1.9.1' for 'git' was not found\n", "stdout": "Reading package
> lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading state
> information...\n", "stdout_lines": ["Reading package lists...",
> "Building dependency tree...", "Reading state information..."]}

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Git package with that specific version is as follows:

```
git=1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.2
```

Your task should be:

```
apt: name=git=1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.2 state=present
```

Regards

Comment: Yes brilliant.  I used `dpkg -s git` to find the version ( `1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3` in my case).

Answer (score 9):

You don't need two tasks for updating cache and installing. Your playbook should look like:

```
---
- hosts: "www"
  tasks:
  - name: Install dependencies
    apt:
      name:
        - git=1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.2
      state: installed
      update_cache: yes
```

note that Ansible supports wildcarding so you don't necessarily need the full version string

Comment: Hey thanks @smiller171 .  The cache update can sometimes take a long time so I just keep it separate as a way of understanding how the Ansible script is progressing and where any failure/problem might lie.  Regarding the wildcarding, would something like:  `- git=*1.9.1*` work?

Comment: I don't think I've used the wildcarding myself, was just seeing it in the docs. Best way to find out is to run a quick test